# Element Offset Including Scroll

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, offset

To get an elements offset I use:

```
function(el) {
    if(el && el.parentNode) {
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        while(el) {
            x += el.offsetLeft;
            y += el.offsetTop;
            el = el.offsetParent;
        }
        return {x: x, y: y};
    }
    return null;
}
```

and to get its scroll offset I use:

```
function(el) {
    if(el && el.parentNode) {
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        while(el) {
            if(el && el.parentNode) {
                x += el.scrollLeft;
                y += el.scrollTop;
                el = el.parentNode;
            } else {
                el = null;
            }

        }
        return {x: x, y: y};
    }
    return null;
}
```

Problem is I can't figure out how to merge these two functions together so I can get an elements offset including any scrolling thats been done on the page. When setting an elements position I usually just have to reference both functions, but it seems like it makes sense to just get the total offset in one function. How can I achieve this? Is it event a good idea to do this all in one function, or are there specific use cases when it would be a good idea to get the offset without the scroll?

Comment: Why would you ever want scrollLeft/Top included with offset? Why would you ever want to accumulate totally unrelated elements' scrollLeft/Tops? If a div is scrolled to 40, and body to 200, what could I use the number 240 for?

Comment: @Esailija to find the absolute position of an element in the view box, possibly?

Comment: The idea is to be able to get an elements actual position on the screen, if a div with overflow auto has been scrolled down the actual position would have to include the scroll position to get the actual position on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You mean something like this?*

```
function f (el) {
  var offset = (function(el) {
    if(el && el.parentNode) {
      var x = 0;
      var y = 0;

      while(el) {
        x += el.offsetLeft;
        y += el.offsetTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
      }

      return {x: x, y: y};
    }

    return null;
  })(el);

  var scroll = (function(el) {
    if(el && el.parentNode) {
      var x = 0;
      var y = 0;

      while(el) {
        if(el && el.parentNode) {
          x += el.scrollLeft;
          y += el.scrollTop;
          el = el.parentNode;
        } else {
          el = null;
        }
      }

      return {x: x, y: y};
    }

    return null;
  })(el);

  return { x: offset.x + scroll.x, y: offset.y + scroll.y }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this without iterating the dom twice?